# Update ListView in UpdateService android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-service, android-adapter

I have an activity and an Update Service in that;
In That Activity I have a ListView witch get data from a sqlite db;
I Update My Sqlite database in UpdateService when the program is run or not (Work in the background);
I Want when my data updated , if the Program is running then the listview Update for new data;
How can I do it ?
Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing something similar last week, in my case I needed to create a BroadcastReciever in my activity and register the service in the broadcast and when my service finish, it send a message with method sendBroadcast(Intent) that will be recieved for all the broadcastRecievers registered. In this case, your activity.

I give you a tutorial to see the process. Try it and goog luck!

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Answer (score 0):

every time your sqlite db is updated with new info invoke your list updating methode,you can do it in a different service. you launch this service in the Oncreate and stop it when Onstop is called  or when you get out of your app.